# how to give draggable element into specific location

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I am trying to move my JQuery UIdraggable container into div(id="frame") but it is dragging everywhere in the webpage. So how can I move my draggable container into specific div(id="frame").So please give me a way to solve this problem. I am trying to make my own custom product designer plugin for which this my first feature.Here is my code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Dragg</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

  <style>
  #draggable { 
    overflow:hidden;
    width:  100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  #frame {
   overflow:hidden;
    width:  350px;
    height: 500px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border : 1px solid black; 
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
      <input type = "file" id="inputFileToLoadOuter">
    <input type = "button" onclick = "loadImageFileAsURL(1)" value = "LoadOuterImage">

<input type = "file" id="inputFileToLoadInner">
<input type = "button" onclick = "loadImageFileAsURL(2)" value = "LoadInnerImage">

<div id="frame">
  <img src="" id="OuterImg" style="width: 100% ; height:100%" />
</div>

<div id="draggable">
  <img src="" id="InnerImg" style="width: 100% ; height:100%" />
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).resizable().draggable();
  } );

  function loadImageFileAsURL(pos)
  {
      if(pos == 1){
        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoadOuter").files;
      }else{
        var filesSelected = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoadInner").files;
      }
      if (filesSelected.length > 0)
      {
          var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

          if (fileToLoad.type.match("image.*"))
          {
              var fileReader = new FileReader();
              fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
              {
                  if(pos == 1){
                    var imageLoaded = document.getElementById("OuterImg");  
                  }else{
                    var imageLoaded = document.getElementById("InnerImg");
                  }
                  imageLoaded.src = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
              };
              fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
          }
      }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

plunker : https://plnkr.co/OubL3Uw0G7gi4d01yx0V

Answer (score 1):

Modify your #draggable object to this

```
$("#draggable").resizable().draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
});
```

and add this to make you #frame droppable

```
$('#frame').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable',
})
```

Read up the jqueryui docs on this, there is much more you can achieve with this. See here https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#photo-manager

Comment: It is not working . Still my draggable object is moving everywhere. I want my draggable object only moving in frame object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use accept of droppable. Like this

```
$('#frame').droppable({
    accept: '#draggable',
})
```

It will solve you problem :)

For more knowledge visit
[JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#accepted-elements)